# Using three examples with "range from"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

When using *range from* with two examples, it could be:

> I should note that our current users range from juniors to graduates.

But when using three examples:

> I should note that our current users range from juniors, to seniors, to graduates.

It doesn't sound correct? What are the rules?

Answer (score 5):

A range extends from one point to another. It is possible to express the extent between the two end points, as in your first example, but there is no reason why intermediate points cannot be included, as in your second example.

Comment: So my second example is correct grammatically?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.

Comment: Perhaps not in OP's *particular* case, but in some contexts I might prefer to replace the first ***to*** with ***through*** (or even abandon my cultural heritage and go for ***thru*** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you please provide me with an example of how you would use **through**?

Comment: @Grunge Thing: A typical context for me might be [red through orange to yellow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22red+through+orange+to+yellow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I'd be more likely to use ***through*** either to make sure my audience realised these *were* actually "ordered" positions on a continuum (not just arbitrarily-chosen instances), or to emphasise the ***progressive** nature* of the reference rather than simply the ***breadth*** of things covered.

Answer (score 3):

*Range* has a slightly different meaning in the two cases.

- The first case is about a range of values, from one *limit/extreme* to another.
- The second, which I would express using "*range **among** juniors, seniors, and graduates*" is about an enumeration: any of the indicated values is a candidate.

In the second case, the enumeration could be understood as exhaustive (*only* juniors, seniors, and graduates) or it could be understood as indicative/exemplary (candidates include juniors, seniors, and graduates - and possibly others). Context should disambiguate, if only one meaning is intended.

Some might argue that "*among*" implies *only*. That's certainly one strong meaning, so "*range among*" has a fairly strong connotation of *only these*. But without further clarification it does leave open the possibility that there are other values that are also candidates.

Comment: Ranging among is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Range from ... through ... to ...**

"I should note that our current users range from juniors, through seniors, to graduates."

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is not entirely incorrect to use 'range from' in the way you have, it is pushing at the boundaries of grammar, in my view. I think if I were using more than two references I would say 'range across'.

'Current users range across juniors, seniors and graduates'.

Comment: Is range across idiomatic? I can't find many references using it that way. I did find a [forum thread questioning this usage](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/range-across.3192348/).

Comment: @JJJ It sounds idiomatic to me, and is what I would use. Though, as I'm sure you appreciate, one person's idiom may be another's gibberish. The English language  is not of the nature of a straitjacket.

Answer (score 1):

**Range from ... over ... to ... ?**

I am not sure this is a correct answer, but since none has been accepted yet, I might as well try:

> I should note that our current users range from juniors *over* seniors to graduates.

Rather than simply down-vote, critics might also comment ;)

Comment: You must be sure of the worth of this answer to post it! However, I would use *through* rather than *over,* I think. "Over" might imply "pass over" without actually including that class in the continuum.

Answer (score 1):

I think "I should note that our current users range from juniors to seniors and graduates."? can give the same meaning.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: 1. If we think juniors as the base point, there is no need to use "senior" as the mid point. Thus, "seniors" is not a way point, it is one of the end point like "graduates". If we take the sentence as two separate sentence ;

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Please edit it into your answer.