# meaning of "to immigration" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation, sentence-meaning

Does it mean "climate change for immigration" or "climate change" and "immigration" are 2 different issues?

In areas that range from occupational safety to climate change to immigration, legislators might benefit if they can delegate authority to others – and blame them.

Comment: As established early in the sentence - they are talking about a range of policies, meaning when addressing several topics including occupational safety, climate change, immigration etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In phrase,

> In areas that range from occupational safety to climate change to immigration

writer is mentioning the range of concerned areas.

Check [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148428/using-three-examples-with-range-from) too.

Comment: It would be better to post the most important information from the linked answer here instead of making people click through and read the whole page